# detect change in a website and know which parts has changed

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to monitor the website if it got changed, and if changed to tell me which part got changed. I did a python script that checks the whole page if changed by comparing the old and the new hash. I want to know which part has changed.

Comment: Should be doable with `diff`. I would save the initial HTML and always diff the results. But comparing hash as first step is kinda neat

Comment: Do you have a code in which I can see ?

Comment: `diff` is a tool you can is typically found in Linux distros. A similar equivalent would be `fc.exe` in Windows. You could use `subprocess.call` and direct `diff` to your new HTML page, and the old one. Then, capture the output and process it. That will tell you where the changes happened.